# Hierarchal groupby and counting the occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to run a script that will capture the amount of unique parts we have in inventory per region. For example, I have the dataframe below (it also includes a lot of other columns, but these are the only relevant ones):

| Region | Part Number |
| --- | --- |
| Region 1 | Part 1 |
| Region 2 | Part 1 |
| Region 3 | Part 1 |
| Region 1 | Part 2 |
| Region 2 | Part 2 |
| Region 3 | Part 2 |
| Region 1 | Part 3 |
| Region 2 | Part 3 |
| Region 3 | Part 3 |

I would like to have my script provide a new dataframe that looks like this

| Region | Part Number | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Region 1 | Part 1 | 1 |
|  | Part 2 | 1 |
|  | Part 3 | 1 |
| Region 2 | Part 1 | 1 |
|  | Part 2 | 1 |
|  | Part 3 | 1 |
| Region 3 | Part 1 | 1 |
|  | Part 2 | 1 |
|  | Part 3 | 1 |

I tried using the groupby and value_counts method below but it doesn't seem to be counting the number of parts per region properly.

```
InventorySummary = InventoryRawData.groupby(['Region'])['Part Number'].value_counts()
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `InventorySummary = InventoryRawData.groupby(['Region', 'Part Number']).value_counts()`

Comment: What is wrong with the output of your code?

Comment: @ZLi, I don't know why but it's applying other columns from the InventoryRawData dataframe into the InventorySummary dataframe as well (such as Part Name and Address). The totals seem to be wrong as well. I believe it's because of the additional columns.

Comment: @NuriTaş, the totals I'm getting are for all occurrences of the parts and not just the number of occurrences per part per region.